# Parted: Wrong disk size reported on new 3TB hard drive

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, gparted, parted

I have a brand new WD Blue 3TB HDD (WD30EZRZ). After having fiddled with it too much (trying to initialize it to GPT on Windows with various system freezes because of whatever reason, etc) ...

I wanted to start from scratch and re-initialize the hard drive on my Ubuntu laptop. I connected the hard drive with a Quickport Combo USB 2.0 connector. Here's the output for the following commands:

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb

Disk /dev/sdb: 2 TiB, 2199023255040 bytes, 4294967295 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

So clearly, the size is wrong. It should be 3 TB. Note that the `print` command within the `parted` utility reports the following:

```
Error: /dev/sdb: unrecognised disk label
Model: WDC WD30 EZRZ-00Z5HB0 (scsi)                                       
Disk /dev/sdb: 2199GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:
```

So I set a GPT disk label with `mklabel gpt` as the HDD is (actually) larger than 2TB.
`print` then gives:

```
Model: WDC WD30 EZRZ-00Z5HB0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 2199GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End  Size  File system  Name  Flags
```

This is great as it at least correctly identifies it as a WD disk with the correct serial number, but still it reports the size as 2199GB (~2TB in non-disk-manufacturer-speech).

When I want to make a new partition with a size of 3GB with `mkpart primary 0.00TB 3.00TB` the following happens:

```
Error: The location 3.00TB is outside of the device /dev/sdb.
```

Weirdly, using `mkpart primary 0.00TB 2.68TB` (or an other, lower upper bound than 2.68TB) seems to work, but the partition is still not bigger than 2199GB:

```
Model: WDC WD30 EZRZ-00Z5HB0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 2199GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 1      1049kB  2199GB  2199GB               primary
```

So: I somehow have the problem that the disk itself reports its size as 2TB and not 3TB anymore - I remember that when I first plugged it in it reported it as 3TB but I somehow screwed it up. Apart from that the disk still seems to work correctly.

**Big question:** How can I "reset" it to factory default? I heard that writing zeros to the whole disk might solve it, but I am not sure whether it's worth the effort as it might take a looooong time. There's the WD Data Guard utility for Windows but maybe there's a Linux alternative? Or maybe the solution is easier than rewriting it with zeros all over.

**Update**: In the meantime, I also ran

```
sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdb
```

and that gives me a sensing error

```
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 04 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 44 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

/dev/sdb:

ATA device, with non-removable media
```

which is problably due to the connection via USB. This might also be (part of) the problem.

Comment: When looking at the specs of the [Quickport Combo USB 2.0 connector](https://en.sharkoon.com/product/1686/09251#specs), it only supports 2TB disks.

Comment: Damn. That's probably it. Will try connecting it via another method (SATA, eSATA - which led to crashes, but who knows).